# How would you extend nested unconstrained Generics in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you extend an array of `Measurement`s without constraining it to a certain `UnitType`?

```swift
import Foundation

extension Array where Element == Measurement { // ERROR: Reference to generic type 'Measurement' requires arguments in <...>

    var sum: Double? {
        // `UnitType` doesn’t matter here
        reduce(0, { $0 + $1.value })
    }

}

let array = [
    Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitVolume.bushels),
    Measurement(value: 2, unit: UnitLength.fathoms),
]

array.sum // expecting `3`
```

[Updated with example]

Comment: Please edit your question and show what is your goal. What are you trying to achieve? What is your method supposed to do with a generic element?

Comment: I don’t have anything specific in mind. Just learning Swift in general and am curious about these Generics now. I will try to think of a good example.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan. I updated the question with an example. How would I achieve functionality like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a protocol, make `Measurement` conform to it and constrain the collection `Element` to that protocol:

```
protocol Valued { 
    var value: Double { get }
}

extension Measurement: Valued { }
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element: Valued {
    func test() {
        print(self)
    }
    // note that it is pointless to sum different types of units
    var sum: Double {
        reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
    }
    // you would need to cast every element to the appropriate unit type before calculating its sum
    var totalLengthInMeters: Double {
        reduce(0) {
            $0 + (($1 as? Measurement<UnitLength>)?.converted(to: .meters).value ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let value: Double = 10
let meters: Measurement<UnitLength> = .init(value: value, unit: .meters)
let feet = meters.converted(to: .feet)

let measurements = [meters,feet]
measurements.test()  // [{value 10, unit "m"}, {value 32.80839895013123, unit "ft"}]
// note that it is pointless to sum different types of units
measurements.sum  // 42.80839895013123
// you would need to cast every element to the appropriate unit type before calculating its sum
measurements.totalLengthInMeters  // 20
```